# OBSERVABLE PARAMS AND COMPONENT RE-USE

Tags: angular, routes

In Routing & Navigation tutorial for angular 2, section OBSERVABLE PARAMS AND COMPONENT RE-USE, the tutorial said  "By default, the **router reuses a component instance** when it re-navigates to the same component type without visiting a different component first. The parameters can change between each re-use."

I created  static counters and put  console.log inside ngOnInit of hero-list, hero-detail component, Crisis-list, Crisis-detail component. I can see those counters got increased every time I navigate back and for "without visiting a different component first".  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

"By default, the router reuses a component instance when it re-navigates to the same component type **without visiting a different component first.**"

It would resuse the same component instance when you set up a router guard, which is an intermediary service that has the ability to prevent the router from navigating somewhere, effectively navigating back to the same component.

Comment: by " set up a router guard" you mean the canactivate, deactivate?

Comment: Yep. Thats the one

Comment: the plunker example has guards in place already. I don't see the crisis-detail component got resused